# Windows 7: Japanese not displaying in Windows

Tags: windows-7, language, unicode

I cannot view Japanese characters in Windows 7. Even filenames that contain Japanese characters show up as squares in folders. Or error boxes that come up in Windows that would normally contain Japanese are all squares.

I've tried running Windows Update, no language packs appear (sounds like I already have it installed). Under region in Control Panel, I tried changing the Format to Japanese... and it didn't help. Even under Region and Language it has square boxes where Japanese characters should be.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think you need to install language pack by windows update.

Comment: As mentioned, I checked and none appear (and I know that would have been the first thing I installed a while ago).

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know why I skiped that line :)

Comment: In windows update, some times, Language packs disappears. Because there were an important update. If you have any update, currently not installed, install it/them first. After that, check windows update again and language packs might be appeared in the list. I have this situation many times before.

Comment: Windows is fully updated, nothing is left listed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem probably stems from the fact that you're font chache probably is corrupted; delete the file `C:\Windows\system32\FNTCACHE.DAT` and restart, your problem should be solved.